# Excel 2013 3 color scale referencing a different cell

Tags: windows

Okay I have looked for an answer everywhere and can't seem to find one.. Have spent over 4 hours looking. here is my question.

```
A   B
```

1

2

I want to color `A1` based on the value in `B1`. The color scheme I want is `solid green/yellow/red` where `0=red 1=yellow and anything equal to or greater than 2 is green.` Now I Know that I can write three separate rules to accomplish this but I'm trying to use a specific function in excel. This is where I am going 
Under conditional `formating>New Rule>Format` all cells based on there values. then I am selecting 3 color scale for format style. it gives me 3 options `MIN/MID/MAX`. for `MIN` under type I am selecting formula and likewise for `MID` and `MAX`. I can't seem to find a formula that will color `A1` using this specific excel feature. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to give up.  This is really simple to do but you need to do it with 3 "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" rules.   Any reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured using the built in feature would be easier in the long run... Why would they have this as a feature and not have it usable?.

Comment: don't be silly, you WILL be using a built in feature. you're just looking at the wrong feature.  That feature is for when you have a full spectrum of values and you want them placed in a scale. here you're going for discrete cases which is what they made the other rule for. It's like pastinging video clips into Word and then complaining you don't like the video player interface.  As pennace, mark this as the answer and move along.